# Unity & C# - car going a little bit unsmooth on ramp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a racing game. When the car I made is going up on a ramp, it becomes a bit jittery. Don't think it's the camera issue as the game looks smooth on plain grounds and when going down a ramp.
This is the video of the jittery car movement on ramp:
https://youtu.be/6YC6SLsokCw

I followed this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqATTzJmFDY&list=PLllUqr_Vxwvto-j8J-Fk2XmjQhn2PcwlZ&index=2

I noticed that in this tutorial, the author's final outcome is also a bit jittery on ramps.
This is the code:

```
    {
        sphereRb.transform.parent = null;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        speedInput = 0;
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
        {
            GetInputForMoving(forwardAccel);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
        {
            GetInputForMoving(reverseAccel);

        }

        turnInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (grounded)
        {
            Turning();
        }

        SetWheelsRotation();

        transform.position = sphereRb.transform.position;
    }

    


    void GetInputForMoving(float directionAccel)
    {
        speedInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * directionAccel * multiplier;
    }

    void Turning()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles + new Vector3(0f, turnInput * turnStrength * Time.deltaTime, 0f));

    }

    void SetWheelsRotation()
    {
        leftFrontWheel.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(leftFrontWheel.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, (turnInput * maxWheelTurn) - 180, leftFrontWheel.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);
        rightFrontWheel.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rightFrontWheel.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, (turnInput * maxWheelTurn), rightFrontWheel.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        grounded = false;
        RaycastHit hit;


        //if hits ground
        if (Physics.Raycast(groundRayPoint.position, -transform.up, out hit, groundRayLength, whatisGround))
        {
            grounded = true;

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
        }

        if (grounded)
        {
            Moving();
        }
        else
        {
            Dropping();
        }

        
    }

    void Moving()
    {
        sphereRb.drag = dragOnGround;
        if (Mathf.Abs(speedInput) > 0)
        {
            sphereRb.AddForce(transform.forward * speedInput);
        }
    }

    void Dropping()
    {
        sphereRb.drag = 0.1f;
        sphereRb.AddForce(Vector3.up * -gravityForce * 100);
    }
```

Please help I am really struggling. Sorry for my English, thanks in advance!

Comment: The first line should be "void Start()", sorry I didn't include it in the code above.

Comment: I don't find it jittery on ramps in the video...

Comment: If you go to 31:42 of the video, and play it in 0.25x speed, you'll see that it's jittery. This is not a problem in this video, but because I want my camera to be much closer to the car, the jitteriness is easily spotted.

Comment: Agree with @rustyBucketBay .. I don't really see what exactly you are referring to .. if you put the video to 0.25x speed everything appears jittery of course ^^ .. can you define jittery a bit clearer for us?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Sorry I should have made it clearer. I uploaded the video of the jittery car movement on ramp above, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The car movement actually looks fine and seems to translate smoothly.

**The real issue is the car rotation**.

If you look at this line :

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;
```

You are telling the car to align its y-axis according to the [mesh normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)).
However, [a slope or ramp will never be perfectly curved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keQYz.png). Polygons are shaping the slope and **the normals between each "part" of the slope change abruptly : this is why the car rotation is so steep along the slope**. *You can see it in the Scene view by enabling the wireframe shading mode (option available just under the "Scene" tab).*

**What you can do is interpolate between the current car rotation and the target rotation with something like the code below** :

```
Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, hit.normal) * transform.rotation;

float angle = Vector3.Angle(transform.up, hit.normal);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, angle * Time.fixedDeltaTime * rotateSpeed);
```

You'll have to tweak the rotation speed until it matches what you feel is OK.
[Quaternion.RotateTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) will smoothly interpolate between the current rotation and the target rotation at the speed of *angle x rotateSpeed* degrees per second. There are better ways to do all of these but I hope this will unlock you with what you currently have.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, it works now! I have been stuck at this problem for so long, you are my life savor!